# Readonly lens for a function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless

I have a case class like:

case class Person(name, birthDate, many other fields) { def something = //compute it from the fields }

What i would really like in the end is to have lenses for name, birthDate, and a readonly lens for something, and if possible compose them together to have a single lens for setting name/birthDate and reading name/birthDate/something

From my limited knowledge it does not seem possible (in shapeless i get an error when creating lens for the something function)

Maybe it's possible in other lens libraries or maybe there's a refactor i need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that optics in general solve the issue of two-way access (getting/settings something if possible), there is no such thing as *read only lenses*.

So, whether you use shapeless or Monocle or something else you cannot do it this way.

However, nothing stops you from doing:

```
// updates person
(lens1 composeLens lens2 composeLens personLens).modify(...)
// gets Person and reads "read only" property
(lens1 composeLens lens2 composeLens personLens).get(object).something
```

About optics in general there is a nice article about them and how you can use them with Monocles.

EDIT. Well, perhaps you could design something to have "read only" optics - that is Prism which always fails to update, but that would be a terrible abomination of the idea I believe. Then you would not work on Person but on some coproduct of Person, but that would be awkwardly counter intuitive, so I do not even start to think how could it be implemented.

Comment: Monocle does define a `Getter` optic that may be relevant here.

Comment: Well, one can define Setter to use `???` and create Lens manually, without macros or derivation. But that kind of defeat the purpose of using functional style...